# Forcing GC.Collect() to reduce chances of running during time sensitive code?

Tags: c#, performance, garbage-collection

During an interview,
I was asked to come up with a way to ensure a block of code in c# can run in consistent time to meet a hypothetical time requirement.
The interviewer mentioned that one way is to invoke the garbage collector to collect before the block of code is executed such that it significantly reduces the probability of the GC running again during that block of code. It was applied to accurate time-based measurements of a medical device, where garbage collection can affect those measurements.

It makes sense to me, but I could not find any information backing that. The general consensus I reviewed is to never call GC.Collect(), and the exceptions did not include this scenario.

Can running GC.Collect() truly reduce the probability of it running anytime soon? Is this the right approach to do this using the .net framework? Does GC.Collect() collect for other CLR programs too or is it only applicable to the current process?

Comment: Given that the GC runs at indeterminate times, I'd be very wary at anyone invoking it and thinking it won't run again during their highly critical section of code.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I would not want the correctness of my medical device software to rely on the vagaries of the GC scheduling algorithm. The authors of that scheduling algorithm and the authors of the device code are not talking to each other.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jared's answer is of course excellent. To add a few other points:

> Can running GC.Collect() truly reduce the probability of it running anytime soon?

Yes.

> Is this the right approach to do this using the .net framework?

I would not want the correctness of software that has human-life-safety-critical functions to depend on probabalistic *guesses* about the *undocumented* behaviour of the collector.

That said: you should do a WaitForPendingFinalizers after the collection. Remember, finalizers run on their own thread, and that might be taking up processor time.

> Does GC.Collect() collect for other CLR programs too or is it only applicable to the current process?

Collecting cleans up managed memory in the current process, so if you have multiple appdomains in one process, collecting in one appdomain collects in the others. It does not go cross process.

Comment: You can also set GCSettings.LatencyMode to GCLatencyMode.LowLatency or GCLatencyMode.SustainedLowLatency to suppress collections - just be sure you don't run out of memory. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384202.aspx

Answer (score 12):

It is definitely **possible** that running a `GC.Collect` will reduce the probability that it happens during the code that immediately follows.  There are many definitive scenarios you could draw up under which it would have this exact behavior.  For example if the very next allocation would cause a collect and the `GC.Collect` freed at least the amount of memory allocated during the scenario.

However it's something I would **never** rely on being true.  There is absolutely no guarantee that this will be the case.  In fact it's possible that the collection wouldn't occur during the scenario and the time to run the forced `GC.Collect` could exceed the scenario time itself.

The only way to guarantee that `GC.Collect` won't run during a given scenario is to

1. Don't allocate any memory
2. Don't let anyone else call `GC.Collect`

Extremely hard to guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

what you could possibly do, is specify to disable concurrent/background garbage collection through app.config: 
[Concurrent Garbage Collection on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1stbec%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: How is that going to help?

Comment: it would disable running GC.collect on a background thread, so he can control what happens when the critical code runs

Comment: But it doesn't do anything to stop GC from running on the current thread.